# ui-router does not work with parameters in route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For some reason it does not work as expected for routes with parameters. It does not even render src attribute for such anchors. I made a simple [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/OGaKma9XO5QB25lIN0fi?p=preview) to demonstrate this and here is the code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a ui-sref="categories/foo">category</a>
    <a ui-sref="blah">blah</a>
</body>
```

and routes:

```
$stateProvider
.state 'blah',
  url: 'blah'
.state 'categories',
  url: "categories/:name"
```

First work fine, second - not. Why this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to Navigate to state, with params
ui-sref also takes an state name as function like syntax with object of params(you want to pass to state) as an argument

So replace

```
<a ui-sref="categories/foo">category</a>
```

with

```
<a ui-sref="categories({name:'foo'})">category</a>
```

Comment: Not a very obvious solution. Nothing about it in documentation. Thanx for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify params like this (using the routes you have defined):

```
<a ui-sref="categories({name:'foo'})">category</a>
```